# Is there any ways to count posts in categories?

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I have nearly 500 categories in my web site. I want to add a function to count posts in each category. Since the categories are too many, i can't try to add posts id or name to each category code. I need wordpress to do it automatically for each category. Is there any way you can show me to do that?

{

```
                    <a href="<?php echo $collection_link; ?>">
                        <h5 class="text-center card-title">
                            <?php the_category(); ?>
                        </h5>
                    </a>
                    <a href="<?php echo $collection_link; ?>">
                        <p class="text-center d-flex justify-content-center card-text">
                            <?php //this is where post count should be displayed ?>
                        </p>
                    </a>

                </div><!-- end card-body -->}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using the default categories, then you may try this:

```
 $categories = get_the_category();

if ( ! empty( $categories ) ) {
    foreach( $categories as $cat ){
        echo $cat->name . " " . $cat->count;
    }   
}
```

$Categories will be an array of cat objects. So if it's no empty then you'll be able to access to each cat and retrieve it's props.

Answer (score 1):

inside `category.php` that would be

```
$category = get_queried_object();
$count = $category->category_count;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function count_cat_post($category) {
if(is_string($category)) {
    $catID = get_cat_ID($category);
}
elseif(is_numeric($category)) {
    $catID = $category;
} else {
    return 0;
}
$cat = get_category($catID);
return $cat->count;
}

// Usage
echo  count_cat_post('1');
echo  count_cat_post('General');
```

Taken from [here](https://www.isitwp.com/count-all-posts-in-category/). A simple google search would have gave your answer!

If you're using the `the_category()` function, you will need to filter a post count in to that function. [This answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/50880) on a post over at WordPress Stack Exchange explains how to do that. Please note that `the_category()` function is actually just `echo get_the_categories();` so the filter in the linked answer should work for you.

For completeness, here's the code from the answer linked above.

```php
add_filter('get_the_categories', 'wpse50876_the_counter');

function wpse50876_the_counter($cats){
    foreach($cats as $cat){
        $cat->cat_name = $cat->cat_name.'('.$cat->count.')';
    }
    return $cats;
}
```

Comment: That needs category id or name for each category. I have lots of categories can't do that one by one

Comment: Where do you want to display the post count? You must be looping through your categories somewhere to display them. You would echo the function within the loop and pass something like `$category->term_id` into the function.

Comment: I need the post count to be displayed under each category name that is displaying in my blog page template. single.php file is using this template for each post I create

Comment: Can you post the part of your code that displays the category in your original question so that we can see how your template is set up?

Comment: I did. Is that enough?

Comment: @MahShad I have updated my answer based on your code. Please check to see if it helps.

Comment: how can I use that code? I pasted it in function.php. It isn't working when I echo it in my code